# PostgreSQL: Calculate Average Handling Time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample table that looks like this

[image]

I need to to a SQL script to get the Average Handling Time of a Case, I researched for suggestions but never worked with timestamps and I'm really lost on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract one `timestamp` from another, you get an `interval`. And you can calculate the average over intervals.

```
select avg(close_timestamp - create_timestamp)
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the `AVG` of the difference of the timestamp.

```
SELECT agent, avg(close_timestamp - create_timestamp) average_timestamp
FROM your_table
GROUP BY agent
ORDER BY agent
```

You can format the solution for obtain it in days/hours/minutes/seconds.